# Question about mathematical integration for a differential equation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to coding, so have patience please. I have an exercise where the aim is to solve a differential equation, where there is a function that has an integral of the form dx cos(x)**2 between 0 and t.

I've tried defining a function, then using the definition to attempt to get a final value at the end of the programme.

```
import numpy
from scipy import integrate
def dydt(C,y,t):
    return -C*y
def f_2(x):
    return numpy.sin(x)**2
def C(t):
    return 1+ integrate.quad(f_2,0,t)
t=numpy.linspace(0,10,100)
y=integrate.odeint(dydt,[1.0],t)
```

This is the error I'm getting: TypeError: dydt() missing 1 required positional argument: 't' --> I know I have clearly defined my t, so what am I doing wrong? Cheers!

Comment: `dydt(C,y,t):` does not use `t`. You can just define it as `dydt(C,y):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`dydt(C,y,t)` should be `dydt(C,y)`**

```
import numpy
from scipy import integrate
def dydt(C,y):
    return -C*y
def f_2(x):
    return numpy.sin(x)**2
def C(t):
    return 1+ integrate.quad(f_2,0,t)
t=numpy.linspace(0,10,100)
y=integrate.odeint(dydt,[1.0],t) # works fine

print(y)
```

Comment: Yep, that's the maths from me. Thanks